# Trouble removing the Pilcrow sign from Database or even in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, special-characters

I've been trying to get rid of the "Pilcrow" sign from the database or in my jsp page using the replace function() but nothing seems to work for me. Please guide me what is it that I'm doing wrong.

I did go through some of the questions asked previously on SO ,  like I did a replace on the Database level but nothing happened, the pilcrow sign is still there.

while I was also thinking of doing like a split in my JSP page like where I define a byte array of the ASCII code of pilcrow which is 244 but I'd need an unsigned byte.I'm pasting this which I tried

```
if(tempDesc.contains("¶")|| tempDesc.contains("&para;") ){
  tempDesc = tempDesc.replace("¶",""); 
  v[3] = tempDesc;
}else{
  v[3] = tempDesc; 
}
```

I've tried so many things , just pasting a couple of things I tried.

I just want some ideas that I should use to implement this get done.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried replacing the char instead? Or even the ascii value of the character?

Comment: @km1: I tried to do that too like this 'String tempDesc = getDescription(p);
   byte[] b = new byte[]{(byte)244};
   String tab = new String(b);
   try{
    String[] temp = Utils.split(tempDesc,tab);
    StringBuffer tempBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
     tempBuffer.append(temp[i]);
    }
    v[3] = tempBuffer.toString();
   }catch(Exception ex){
    v[3] = "Not Found"+tempDesc;
   }'

Comment: This may be silly but I was thinking something like `tempDesc.replace('¶','');` or `tempDesc.replace((char)244, '');` Also, are these characters in the database and you want to filter them out after running a query?

Comment: I did it using regex , so far it's working fine for me :p

String clean = tempDesc.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z \\-,\\.]", "");